# RegExp to allow only positive integer and decimal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am trying to match character with regular expression to allow only positive number and decimal values. The below regular expression working fine but I can able to fill two decimal point.

jQuery

```
$(".qtyValidation").keypress(function (e) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/[^0-9\.]/g)) return false;
});
```

Input Field

```
<input class="mt-my-prices-product-quantity qtyValidation" min="0" type="number" value="1">
```

It is disallwoing negavite numbers but it is allowing 1..2 Or 1.56.45 like this.

The regular expression should allowed with one decimal dots only.

Comment: [`^[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/cH9fG9/1)?

Comment: @Tushar, no, that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).match(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/g)) return false;
```

(.[0-9]{1,2})? only allows two decimal

(.[0-9]+)? allows any number of decimals

Comment: This will match any number of decimals, downvoted.

Comment: ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})? will not match any number of decimals. pls explain your comment ?

Comment: Yes, it will. It is blatantly wrong. Run the following in your console: `/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?/.test('123.456')`. To fix this, you would need to add `$` to your expression.

Comment: ya... I forgot $. Thanks.